# ActiveRecord Average on a column where values are numbers of string type

Tags: ruby, string, postgresql, activerecord, average

I am trying to get the average of the values from a column in my database. I am using RoR and ActiveRecord in a postgreSQL database.

`City` is associated with the `categories` table. The `categories` table contains several instances of records with various names like `price_of_coffee` and `price_of_beer`. The column named `value` contains numbers that are `string`s that represent the price of the category.

Here is an example record for `price_of_monthly_utilities`:

```
#<Category id: 774, city_id: 2, name: "price_of_monthly_utilities", data: nil, created_at: "2014-10-24 03:33:54", updated_at: "2014-10-24 03:33:54", value: "290">
```

Right now my code/technique to grab the average is not very pretty.

I call the method from my `cities_controller.rb`:

```
@average_price_of_coffee = City.calculate_coffee_price(params[:id])
```

Here is the code in the `city.rb` model:

```
def self.calculate_coffee_price(id) 
  @coffee_prices = []
  City.find(id).categories.where(name: "price_of_coffee").each do |category| 
    @coffee_prices << category.value.to_f
  end
  @average = (@coffee_prices.sum / @coffee_prices.size).round(2)
end
```

then I display the result in the view file:

```
<strong>Average Price of a coffee: $</strong>
<%= @average_price_of_coffee %>
```

I really want to harness the power of ActiveRecord and be able to use Average!
I also have a feeling the database is not optimally set up --- but I'd like to know if there is any to move forward without changing the DB. Help!

Comment: A better solution would be to change the column(s) to a more appropriate type, but otherwise the type cast in Lomefin's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Rails with PostgreSQL.

I did a cast to integer when asking for the average, like so:

```
city_categories.average("value::int")
```

I don't know if type casting is the same on other databases, but works on Postgres like your problem.

Comment: Type casting is not the same on other databases, but this is the correct solution when using Postgres.

Comment: A type cast error will occur if any of the values in your string column cannot be cast to your desired type – if you run into this problem you may want to add a where statement for the same column, limiting the values to those that look numeric – Postgres has some good regex helpers for that e.g. `WHERE price_of_coffee ~ '^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$' `.

Comment: I took some assumptions, based on the text in the question: That the user is running over PostgreSQL and that the content of the field is always a number. But that method, @Steve is a great helper!

Comment: Note the above regex will match numerics which Postgres can cast including integers and floats with optional leading or trailing dots and zeros i.e. `1`, `0.1`, `.1` and `1.` – if you just need integers you can use something simpler, or in the case of prices, maybe something like `'^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$'`.